# Workaround for :has pseudo class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

While jquery supports it, CSS3 itself does not.  I'm trying to target elements that have specific siblings.

In jquery, I have **$('tr:has(+tr.childrow)')** which lets me target table rows that have another TR immediately under it with the childrow class.

I considered **tr:not(.childrow)** which targets all my non child rows, but it's not quite the same as I could have some rows that aren't followed with a child row.

In other words, target only the rows that have an adjacent sibling with a childrow class

```
<tr><td></td></tr>                    // select me
<tr class="childrow"><td></td></tr>   //   don't select me
<tr><td></td></tr>                    //   don't select me
<tr><td></td></tr>                    //   don't select me
<tr><td></td></tr>                    // select me
<tr class="childrow"><td> </td></tr>  //   not me either
```

Only solution I can think of is to add a class to the "parent" rows and target that directly.

Comment: I am confused by your question, what are you trying to achieve ? You are trying to select every `tr` that has a class `childrow` via CSS, because there is no `tr` wrapper in the html example that you provided?

Comment: I guess a "previous sibling" would be another way to look at it, in which it looks like I will have to add additional markup to select my targets. 

Nicolae, I'm trying to select every TR that comes before a TR containing the childrow class

Comment: What is the difference between first `tr` with `//select me` and third `tr` with `//don't select me` ?

Comment: I don't know how to explain any easier.  They have different adjacent siblings. One is followed by a childrow class, the other is not.